# famo.us Firefox setting z-index doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, z-index, famo.us

I am trying to control the layering of surfaces using zIndex property. It works just fine in Chrome whereas it doesn't in Firefox. After examining the DOM, I observed that the z-index is marked as 0 no matter what we set.

I reproduced the problem in famo.us tutorial code @http://famo.us/university/famous-101/displaying/5/. Replace the tutorial code with the following code. Notice the difference between Chrome and Firefox with the same code.

```
var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var firstSurface = new Surface({
  size: [200, 400],
  content: 'top',
  properties: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FA5C4F',
    zIndex: 10
  }
});

var secondSurface = new Surface({
  size: [300, 200],
  content: 'bottom',
  properties: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    zIndex: 8
  }
});

mainContext.add(firstSurface);
mainContext.add(secondSurface);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to avoid using the zIndex property, because Famo.us does Z indexing for you with their 3D render Engine. To achieve what you wish, use a StateModifier and translate your surfaces in the Z direction.

This now works in FireFox as well. Hope it helps!

```
var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
var Transform  = require('famous/core/Transform');
var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var firstSurface = new Surface({
  size: [200, 400],
  content: 'top',
  properties: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FA5C4F'
  }
});

firstSurface.state = new StateModifier({
    transform: Transform.translate(0,0,10)
});

var secondSurface = new Surface({
  size: [300, 200],
  content: 'bottom',
  properties: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    }
});

secondSurface.state = new StateModifier({
    transform:Transform.translate(0,0,8)
});

mainContext.add(firstSurface.state).add(firstSurface);
mainContext.add(secondSurface.state).add(secondSurface);
```

Comment: Thanks johntraver. I will keep that in mind. I tested using translateZ and it worked. However, I went ahead and tried to see why the z-index wouldn't work. Changing the code in `Surface` as follows fixed the issue

Original:

`element.style.zIndex = (matrix[14] * 1000000) | 0;    // fix for Firefox z-buffer issues`

New:

`element.style['z-index'] = (matrix[14] * 1000000) | 0;    // fix for Firefox z-buffer issues`

After changing this line, I am able to see the z-index values on the DOM reflecting the ones supplied in code. Also, the surfaces are rendered in the correct z-order on the screen.

Comment: Cool! glad you figured it out!

Comment: Those lines are Famo.us were necessary due to a bug in Firefox that has been fixed in v30.0. Previously Firefox didn't obey nested translateZ's, so we needed to enforce zIndexing in order to get proper layering. We'll be removing this on the Famo.us end pending Firefox 30 adoption rates.